# All possible values of the integral

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I find all possible values of the $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz$ which $\gamma$ is a curve from $i$ to $-i$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried to solve with residue theorem, but i can't because $\gamma$ is not closed so I tried to calculate it on $\gamma \cup (-i,i)$ but i can't calculate integral in Im axis.

Comment: If $\gamma : [0;1] \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ is a curve from $i$ to $-i$, then $\gamma_- : t \mapsto \gamma(1 - t)$ is a curve from $-i$ to $i$. Now if you have two curves $\gamma, \gamma'$, then you can concatenate $\gamma$ and $\gamma'_-$ to get a closed curve.